# can browser scrollbar be used instead of iframe scrollbar?

Tags: html, iframe

I have a page with two iframe contents which are split horizontally. The left one is a tree view type and its size is initially zero. The right one is shown always. When the size of the content in the right side iframe increases, it creates a scrollbar. The vertical scrollbar is not shown for the iframe, but the browser scrollbar adjusts for the vertical scrolling.

Can the same be done with the horizontal scrollbar? I have the iframes as scrolling=auto; frameborder=0;height=100% etc. Many of the issues i checked are saying like hiding the scrollbar or aligning problem. i cant seem to find something like this. Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can be done with iframes, but other websites implement scrolling on a small part of the page by setting the rest of the content (container) as `position:fixed` in CSS. So the browser just scrolls based on the inner content.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find how to use it in my page. But I obtained the result by using javascript to adjust the width of iframe to that of the content inside the iframe, by referencing the below page.
[Resize Iframe](http://www.wolfcreekconsulting.com/support/techlib/web/DynamicallyResizedIframesPart2.php)